# How to extract a web page text onthe basis of <p> tag

Tags: curl, html, ruby

[The Punjabi Dictionary (year-1895) web page](http://dsalsrv02.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/getobject.pl?p.0:0.singh) is  available in Creative Commons license. How can i extract the text (words) in between the html `<p>  </p>` tag. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eumekfP4IKQ) describes. But i am new to ruby. I need this data for WikiConference_India_2016.

Comment: See also [Using `sed` to extract text between two tags](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/98217/80216).

Comment: That's what [Xidel](http://www.videlibri.de/xidel.html) is for: `xidel -e //p http://dsalsrv02.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/getobject.pl?p.0:0.singh`

Comment: What operating system? What distro?